# Eigenvectors of function of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear transformation and $f$ be any polynomial. I already know that if $Tv=cv$ for some eigenvalue $c$ and eigenvector $v$, we must have $f(T)v=f(c)v$. Thus, every eigenvector of $T$ is an eigenvector of $f(T)$. Is the converse necessarily true? I know that it does not work for $\mathbf{R}^n$ ($90$ degree rotation), so I think the interesting case is when we are working over an algebraically closed field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that consideration of the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) will satisfy your curiosity.

Focus on the more concrete case of square matrices for a moment. If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and if $p(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, then the Cayley-Hamilton theorem shows that $p(A) = O$, the $n\times n$ zero matrix. Then *every* vector is an eigenvector of $p(A)$ (in a very unsatisfying manner, I admit), while the same cannot necessarily be said of $A$.